# Hide SwiftUI TextField cursor

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I am trying to hide the cursor in TextField and managed to successfully do it using `.accentColor(.clear)`, however in the documentation it is specified that `accentColor` will be deprecated and I should use `.tint(.clear)`, but this doesn't do the job which `accentColor` did. Any help? Do I have to set some other params as well or what is the solution? I really don't want to leave something that is gonna be deprecated in my code

Comment: Just continue using accentColor until it disappears (version: 10000....)

Comment: And switch to using tint after it's deprecated ? :D

Comment: .tint(.clear) is working for me